# AWS CloudFront accelerated bucket origin setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have been using CloudFront to serve content from an S3 bucket. Up to now, the bucket did not have accelerate enabled.

When I enable the Accelerate property on the bucket, the `Accelerated endpoint` changes to:

`my-bucket-name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`

The `Origins` in CloudFront still has the Origin Name:

`my-bucket-name`

The question I have is:

In order for CloudFront to take advantage of the Accelerate speed on the bucket, do I need to change the CloudFront Origin Name from `my-bucket-name` to `my-bucket-name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`?

Or, enabling the Accelerate property on `my-bucket-name` is all I need to do and I can leave CloudFront settings as they are for Accelerate to kick in?

Comment: Are you able to find a solution / work around for the same?   I was also doing some research on this topic to increase speed of website that is on cloudfront.  I could see accelerated end point in s3 serves data more fast

Comment: no. I'm still looking for an answer to this.